# How do I get refreshToken by using old-refreshToken?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

1) I succeed to get refreshToken by code :

```
    public void Register(String code){
        GoogleTokenResponse response = null;
        response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        refreshToken = response.getRefreshToken();                

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken());        

        client = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();            
    }
```

Now I get refreshToken, It is used 2).

2) So, I want get client(class Drive). 
under code for getting 'Drive client'. I think that I should use GoogleRefreshTokenRequest class to get client by refreshToken. Is that true? I did make mistakes?

```
    public Drive GetClient(String refresh){
            httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            GoogleTokenResponse response = null;
            GoogleRefreshTokenRequest req = new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(httpTransport, 
jsonFactory, refresh, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            req.setGrantType("refresh_token");
            try {
                response = req.execute();
                System.out.println("RF token = " + response.getRefreshToken());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GoogleD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

            client = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();             

            return client;
        }
```

3) And, I want get refreshToken by refreshToken. my logic is right?

1. Get access_token, refreshToken by user login.
2. Get client(offline) by refreshToken. - and get refreshToken2.
3. repeat 2

Comment: You dont need to get a new refreshtoken there good almost forever.  What you need to do is use your refresh token to get a New accessToken.

Comment: @LindaL Yup, Thanks. I realized few hours ago...